# Translation of "I wonder if you can buy the bread on your way home"

Tags: grammar, translation

Related to [this question](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/7384/translating-a-can-you-buy-some-bread-b-i-will-buy-it-on-my-way-home-but-i-ha/7390?noredirect=1#comment7254_7390) where I was suggested to lookup the patterns V(으)ㄹ래요 and V(으)ㄹ게요.

In my understanding, and according to one of [my grammar reference](https://www.google.co.kr/books/edition/Basic_Korean/YceWzQEACAAJ?hl=en) these are sentence final endings expressing "willingness", respectively in questions and statements.

Given my former question, mentioned above, and what I just learnt I was trying to translate the following sentence:

> I wonder if you can buy the bread on your way home

My attempt

> 저는 집에 가는길 빵을 살레는지 궁금해요

I explain my reasoning in steps

> 집에 가는길 : On your way home

> 빵을 살레요 : Will you buy the bread

> 저는 집에 가는길 빵을 살레는지 궁금해요: I wonder if you will buy the bread on your way home.

**Questions**:

1. Is the translation grammatically correct? (Regardless of how natural it sounds)
2. Does it sound natural?

The reason of question 1 is that I am not sure of my combination of (으)ㄹ래요 with the noun modifier 는 together with the indirect question 지 ( so the 레는지 I am not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation is not grammatically correct.

The most natural liberal translation

> 집에 가는 길에 빵 살 건가요?

Literal translation

> 저는 당신이 집에 가는 길에 빵을 사려는지 궁금해요.

Your translation is incorrect for the following reasons.

Your use of V"-ㄹ래요" and V'-ㄹ게요" is correct, but they can only occur at the end of a sentence as 'sentence-closing ending'. So, while V"-ㄹ래요" is correct in "Will you buy the bread", it's incorrect in the middle of sentence. When used in the middle of a sentence, V"-려는" be appropriate.

If you're interested in learning more, here's an explanation.

First, you need to understand that "-래요" is a combination of "-래" as a closing ending and "-요" as a respectful ending.
You also need to know that '-래' is short for '-라고 해'(or maybe not, but in your usage it is).
Next, note that '-라고' is a colloquial expression for '-려고', which is strictly grammatically incorrect(this is where native speakers get confused a lot, too).
Finally, when "-려고" is utilized as a formula for another word, it becomes "-려는" with "-는" attached.

And some other awkwardness.

1. Korean often omits the subject. Since you left out "당신"(you), remaining subject "저는" sounds more unnatural.
2. "**On** your way home" should be translated to "집에 가는 길**에**"
   (집에 가는 길 = your way home)

Answer (score 0):

Omitting the subject sounds more natural in Korean. Depending on the context and who you're doing a favor, one can develop several translations.

If the person you're asking is a close friend you can say:

> 집에 오는 길에 빵 사 올래?

More direct and formal translation would be

> 집에 오는 길에 빵 사 올 수 있는지 궁금합니다.